# Preventing uploading of password-protected or corrupt PDF files in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, pdf, file-upload, password-protection, remotipart

I have a ruby on rails 4 app that uses ajax file uploading. Is there a way I can prevent the user from uploading password-protected or corrupt / malformed PDF files?

UPDATE: Just saw this post on checking if a PDF is corrupt using `pdf-reader` gem and it might work but I still need help detecting a locked pdf file:
[Fastest way to check that a PDF is corrupted (Or just missing EOF) in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28156467/fastest-way-to-check-that-a-pdf-is-corrupted-or-just-missing-eof-in-ruby)

---

In case it matters, I'm using:
rails 4.2.5, ruby 2.1.6, remotipart 1.2.1

Comment: Do you have a PDF library for Ruby that can read and verify the PDF is valid? If so, use that. If not, find one, like [pdf-reader](https://github.com/yob/pdf-reader).

Comment: @tadman thank you. I just read about pdf-reader on another post. I'll try it out.